# rename charts in a boolean vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

how are you?
Can someone help me?

I have the following code that generates graphics:

```
Sheets("kips").Select

    Dim i As Integer 'rows
    Dim j As Integer 'columns
    
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For j = 2 To 5
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            '.Name = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
            'Cells(1, j).Address
            .XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
            Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(i, 1)).Address
            .Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
            Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(i, j)).Address
            
            End With
            
        End With
    Next j
```

it works well, but I need these 4 graphics created, come out with a name, because it creates and uses something with "Graph number X" and the rest of the code doesn't work, as I give it a name as soon as I create it he?

here's the rest of the code

```
'Clean the charts
'chart1

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gráfico 12").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gráfico 12").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gráfico 12").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gráfico 12").Activate
    ActiveChart.Legend.Select
    Selection.Delete
    
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gráfico 12").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).Overlap = -27
    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 50
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 32, 96)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vba
For j = 2 To 5
     With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
         .Parent.Name = "Chart_" & (j-1)       '<< name the chartobject (Parent of Chart)
         '...
         '...
```

FYI it would probably be "cleaner" to pass the ChartObject directly to a formatting Sub, instead of name it and then later access it by name

```vba
For j = 2 To 5
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        FormatChart1 .Parent
        '...
        '...
```

Formatting sub:

```vba
Sub FormatChart1(co as chartobject)
    With co
        .Chart.ChartTitle.Delete
        .Chart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete
        .Chart.Axes(xlValue).Delete
        'etc
        'etc
    End with
End sub
```